# Fibonacci recursion ex

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

Again, I'm still working with recursion, I've got a question regarding one of the base cases.

UPD: a and b represent the 1st numbers in the sequence and n is the desired position for the to-be calculated sum.

My code is as follows:

```
public static int fib(int a, int b, int n) {

    if (n <=1) { 
        return a;
    } else if (n == 2) {
        return b;
    } else {
        return (fib(a, b, n - 1) + fib(a, b, n - 2));
    }
}
```

In Line 2, before i started tracing out the program by hand, i kept it as "n<=0" . However, I got a diff answer as i traced and run the program. The problem was at some point n will  = to 1. So I changed the first base case to n<=1 and got same answers.

Now the question is, suppose I called the method as follows: fib(2,3,6)
the answer should be = 21 ( with line 2 = " n<=1")
but when line 2 was "n<=0" the answer was 27.

I would like to know what happens to the program when n eventually = 1 given "n<=0" in Line 2

Comment: Well, what will happen then is that is calls `fib` with `n - 1` and `n - 2` and adds those results (your last else block). Why don't you debug this or write some old school `System.out.println` messages in your program and see for your self? Way faster than asking a question here.

Comment: Read wikipages on [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 1):

The call when n is 1 will generate two extra recursive calls with n as 0 and n as -1.  These two recursive calls will add `a` twice to the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, that's what i figured out ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the nth Fibonacci, simply pass n to the function.

Assuming the sequence is 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 ...

Your algorithm will be

```
if n = 1 return 0
else if n = 2 return 1
else return fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)
```

Comment: While this is an answer, this does not answer the original question. It does not seem that the OP has a problem with the math of the fibonacci sequence, he has more a problem with the borders of the algorithm and recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I actually answered my own question.

You see at some point n = 3,
So the value to be returned will eventually lead to n =1 as follows:

return (Fib(2,3,2)+ Fib(2,3,1))

Now that n = 1 the base case in Line 2 will be executed properly.

whereas if the base case in Line 2 was  " n<=0" then for the case of n =3

return (Fib(2,3,2) + Fib(2,3,1))

then Fib(2,3,1) will cause the method to be called again and will result to n =0 and that will lead to having *n = -1 & n =-2* causing the answers to differ.

//UpDATED: having n =0 & n=-1 will cause the answers to differ

Comment: do you mean "that will lead to having n = 0 & n = -1 causing the answers to differ"?

Comment: Yes I think I mistyped the n values up there..sorry

Answer (score 0):

You have two base cases where both will hit eventually and instead of returning n which would be correct it returns one of the passed and unchanged variables `a` or `b`.

Your code is a messy combination of the two different ways of computing the fibonacci series.
You have the recursive one that is very inefficient:

```
public static int fib(int n) {
    if (n <=1)
        return n;

    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

But, as you see it will compute everything severeal times. If you see the sequence you can iterate from the beginning by having two numbers, a and b, as arguments:

```
a 0 1 1 2 3 5 ...
b 1 1 2 3 5 8 ...
```

To compute the next a, you use b. To compute the new a you add a and b. Thus a more efficient algorithm is:

```
public static int fib(int a, int b, int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return a;

    return fib(b, a+b, n-1);
}
```

Java does not tail call optimize so recursion won't work as well as in other languages that does optimize tail calls, thus an non recursive version of this would be better, like:

```
public static int fib(int n) {
    for(int a=0, b=1;; n--) {
        if (n <= 0)
           return a;
        int tmpa = a;
        a = b;
        b += tmpa;
    }
}
```